# Creating symbolic link to new location after moving C:\Windows\Installer to D: partition

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, junction

I am trying to make some space on my C: partition, an SSD drive, by moving the `C:\Windows\Installer` partition to the `D:` drive (following [this guide](http://www.dunhamtech.com/?p=184)).

The last step is:

> Launch a Command Prompt (as administrator) and execute the following command.:
>
> `junction.exe  c:\windows\installer d:\windows\installer`

When I do that I get the error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>junction.exe C:\Windows\Installer D:\Windows\Installer

Junction v1.06 - Windows junction creator and reparse point viewer
Copyright (C) 2000-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error creating C:\Windows\Installer:
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

When I try to remove the file I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>rmdir C:\Windows\Installer
The directory is not empty.
```

And when I try to look what's inside that folder I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Windows\Installer

C:\Windows\Installer>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F8DE-4477

 Directory of C:\Windows\Installer

File Not Found
```

So, how can I create a symbolic link to the new location (Windows 7)?

Comment: Did you *cut and paste* the folder?

Comment: Have you tried it in Safe Mode?

Comment: @DanielBeck apparently I cut and pasted the folder contents but not the folder itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, after deleting the folder with administrator privileges (it is a hidden system folder so it may be that you don't see it) i got this error message

```
Junction v1.06 - Windows junction creator and reparse point viewer
Copyright (C) 2000-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error creating C:\Windows\Installer:
Zugriff verweigert
```

But no problem, after running the command prompt as administrator it worked.

BTW: You can get the tool here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Comment: Just to add, you no longer have to use **junction**. In newer versions of Windows you can just use the default tool **mklink** for this (symbolic links, hard links, and junctions).